# Kendo UI Grid MasterTableView Equivalent

Tags: kendo-ui, kendo-grid

With the Telerik Ajax Grid Control up can do the following:

```
dataItems = $find("<%= grid.ClientID %>").get_masterTableView().get_dataItems();
```

In order to get the dataItem collection of the grid. There doesn't seem to be a 'get_MasterTableView' for the mvc control, unless I am missing something.

```
dataItems = $("#grid").get_masterTableView().get_dataItems()
```

or

```
dataItems = $("#grid").data("kendoGrid").get_masterTableView().get_dataItems()
```

doesn't seem to work.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do (more info [here](http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/ui/grid#fields-dataSource)):

```
var dataSource = $("#grid").data("kendoGrid").dataSource;
```

or, if you want to get a specific data item, you can do (more info [here](http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/ui/grid#methods-dataItem)):

```
var dataItem = $("#grid").data("kendoGrid").dataItem("tr:eq(1)");
```

**UPDATE:**

If you want to iterate through items, you can use the `data()` method of the datasource object (more info [here](http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/data/datasource#methods-data)):

```
var data = $("#grid").data("kendoGrid").dataSource.data();

for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
    var item = data[i];
    // some code
}
```

Comment: How would you iterate through each item in the datasource object?

Comment: Look at my updated answer. By the way, you can find all this in Kendo UI documentation.